# Appending data frames based on a function in R

Tags: r, selection, plyr

How do I append data frames one after the other to form another data frame?
Whether a data frame would be included or not will be decided by a criteria.

Here is an example data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(MyGroups =sample(LETTERS,100,replace=TRUE),
                 MyInt = sample(c(1:20),100,replace=TRUE))
```

Now, how should I choose groups (A,B,C...) from MyGroups that have mean of variable MyInt greater than 10?

I tried the following without a success. Here, I am appending the data frame into a file based on the given criteria.

```
require("plyr")

keepGrp <- function(df0) { 
  if(max(df0$MyInt < 10)) {df0 <- NULL}
  write.csv(df0,'mytable.txt',append=TRUE,sep=',')
}

ddply(d1,.(MyInt),function(x) keepGrp(x))
```

The desired data frame should be in file mytable.txt
I am fully sure there is a better way to do what I am trying to do.
I would be happy to clarify my question if I need to do so.
I will appreciate of someone can (1) show me a feedback on improving my programming thoughts  (2) give me a solution to my problem.

Comment: Is your goal to create a data.frame, or to create a file? You question starts by asking about a data.frame, but ends by asking about a file.

Comment: I wanted a data frame but then had no idea how to do it. The only thing I could think of is use ddply and send the results to a file and then import data frame from that file

Comment: In your example you have only one data frame. Why do you say you want to append data frames (in plural)? Could you provide a more clear example?

Comment: I said data frame since ddply returns data frames after performing function on each group in the (original) data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you want to calculate the mean by group and only write those that meet a certain threshold to a pre-existing file. If so, why not calculate all the means at once, subset that, then write that out? Here's a one liner that should probably be split into multiples, but I think you'll get the point:

```
write.table(
  subset(
    ddply(d1, "MyGroups", transform, meanval = mean(MyInt)
          ), 
    meanval > 10), 
  "yourcsv.csv", append = TRUE, sep = ",", col.names = FALSE
  )
```

Comment: So, in summary: Create a columns using `transform` and then filter rows using `subset`

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler than you are making it. The function called by `ddply` can either return the subset of data if the criteria are met, or an empty data.frame if not.

```
keepGrp <- function(df0) {
  if(mean(df0$MyInt) > 10) {
    df0
  } else {
    data.frame()
  }
}

res <- ddply(d1, .(MyGroups), keepGrp)
```

Note that your tests inside `keepGrp` was wrong (didn't test the mean of the `MyInt` values) and the grouping of the `ddply` was wrong (should be `MyGroups`, not `MyInt`).

Checking that this is right:

```
> ddply(d1, .(MyGroups), summarise, ave = mean(MyInt))
   MyGroups       ave
1         A 14.200000
2         B  9.600000
3         C  5.600000
4         D  5.600000
5         E  8.000000
6         F 10.500000
7         G  7.333333
8         H 12.000000
9         I  7.333333
10        J  9.500000
11        K 11.000000
12        L 12.375000
13        M 13.250000
14        N 12.000000
15        O 11.666667
16        P  8.625000
17        Q 13.000000
18        R  6.000000
19        S 16.000000
20        T 12.000000
21        U 12.000000
22        V 13.250000
23        W 17.666667
24        X  9.000000
25        Y 12.400000
26        Z 13.750000
> unique(res$MyGroup)
 [1] A F H K L M N O Q S T U V W Y Z
Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

So the ones that appear in `res` are those that have the appropriate mean value for `MyInt`.

Comment: +1 for data.frame() and pointing out **grouping of the ddply was wrong**